# My F# code cannot read XML using XSD template

Tags: f#, .net-core, f#-data

I want to parse data from my bank account in F# that are provided in XML. I have an XSD schema of a statement.

My code reads the schema but it is not able to read the structure. I see the content in XML in data.XElement, however, `data.AccountStatement` property does not exist. The code goes to `None` option and then the application crashes. Do you have any idea why the code loads the schema but cannot work with data in XML?

```
open FSharp.Data
let TestAddress = "TESTADDRESS"
let dateRegex = @"\d{1,2}[.]\d{1,2}[.]\d{4}";
type BankTransactionList = XmlProvider<Schema="Schemas/IBSchema.xsd">
let data = BankTransactionList.Parse(Http.RequestString(TestAddress))

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  let AccountStatement = 
    match data.AccountStatement with
      | Some v -> Some v
      | None -> None //code goes here
  let TransactionList = 
    match AccountStatement.Value.TransactionList with //and crashes here
      | Some v -> Some v
      | None -> None
  for transaction in TransactionList.Value.Transactions do
    printf "%s" transaction.Column22.Value
  0 // return an integer exit code
```

I am developing in .Net Core 2.1. You can see the anonymized example of XML data below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AccountStatement>
    <Info>
        <accountId>X</accountId>
        <bankId>X</bankId>
        <currency>CZK</currency>
        <iban>X</iban>
        <bic>X</bic>
        <openingBalance>X</openingBalance>
        <closingBalance>X</closingBalance>
        <dateStart>X</dateStart>
        <dateEnd>X</dateEnd>
        <idFrom>X</idFrom>
        <idTo>16663326563</idTo>
    </Info>
    <TransactionList>
        <Transaction>
            <column_22 name="ID pohybu" id="22">0</column_22>
            <column_0 name="Datum" id="0">2018-08-25+02:00</column_0>
            <column_1 name="Objem" id="1">0</column_1>
            <column_14 name="Měna" id="14">CZK</column_14>
            <column_5 name="VS" id="5">1023</column_5>
            <column_16 name="Zpráva pro příjemce" id="16">Message</column_16>
            <column_8 name="Typ" id="8">Platba kartou</column_8>
            <column_9 name="Provedl" id="9">Pešík, Jiří</column_9>
            <column_17 name="ID pokynu" id="17">0</column_17>
        </Transaction>
    </TransactionList>
</AccountStatement>
```

Comment: I have never used it with the `Schema` option. Have you tried providing a sample instead?

Comment: Yes, it was working with a sample. I just want to also learn myself the Schema option too.

Comment: Can you please provide also the xsd?

Comment: It is stored here: https://www.fio.cz/xsd/IBSchema.xsd

Comment: I see a target namespace in the xsd, while your sample lacks it. I suspect the sample is not valid unless you add the proper namespace to it

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the schema requires the namespace: "http://www.fio.cz/IBSchema".

Adding the namespace in the document should solve the issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AccountStatement xmlns="http://www.fio.cz/IBSchema">
    <Info>
        <accountId>X</accountId>
        <bankId>X</bankId>
        <currency>CZK</currency>
        <iban>X</iban>
        <bic>X</bic>
        <openingBalance>0</openingBalance>
        <closingBalance>0</closingBalance>
        <dateStart>2000-01-01</dateStart>
        <dateEnd>2001-01-01</dateEnd>
        <idFrom>0</idFrom>
        <idTo>16663326563</idTo>
    </Info>
    <TransactionList>
        <Transaction>
            <column_22 name="ID pohybu" id="22">0</column_22>
            <column_0 name="Datum" id="0">2018-08-25+02:00</column_0>
            <column_1 name="Objem" id="1">0</column_1>
            <column_14 name="Měna" id="14">CZK</column_14>
            <column_5 name="VS" id="5">1023</column_5>
            <column_16 name="Zpráva pro příjemce" id="16">Message</column_16>
            <column_8 name="Typ" id="8">Platba kartou</column_8>
            <column_9 name="Provedl" id="9">Pešík, Jiří</column_9>
            <column_17 name="ID pokynu" id="17">0</column_17>
        </Transaction>
    </TransactionList>
</AccountStatement>
```

I hope your bank is not producing documents lacking the namespace and a schema requiring it.